# Get Hard disk serial number with php on server

Tags: php

I want to get hard disk serial number.
while customer registering the form 
in that HardDiskSerialNumber  i need to store a database table
How I can I do that? with php .

my code :
$serial =  shell_exec('wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber 2>&1');

echo  $serial;

Comment: What operating system is your app hosted on? You may execute system query to reach such info...

Comment: Have a look at phpSysInfo - http://phpsysinfo.github.io/phpsysinfo/

Comment: Which hard disk serial number? I dont see any point in getting the serial number of your server disk, so are you asking if you can get the hard disk serial number of my disk when I register with you?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes .. while you are register the form  meanwhile i am getting hdsn.

Comment: You cannot get PHP to collect that data from my PC. 1) as PHP runs only on your server. 2) As this is my private info. It may be possible to get javascript to get this **but I sincerely doubt it, and hope not**

Comment: wait do you mean getting the hard disk serial number of the user logged in? cos that would be totally crazy

Comment: the purpose i am getting user hard disk serial number,  to install one developed software(client software) with unique key,   so that unique key instead we use hdsn.    If it is possible or not ??

Comment: yes @RiggsFolly   but client requirement\ makes me some struggle like this.

Answer (score -1):

On Linux hosting server you may be able to execute shell command to find the info you need.

```
echo shell_exec('udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda | grep ID_SERIAL');
```

[Harddisk serial number from terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121757/harddisk-serial-number-from-terminal)

Comment: this will give a serial number of web server not for the customer who is registering.